# GraphQL/Relay - How to pass a mutation's input variable into a query on the mutation response?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-mutation

Given a mutation like this (see how `nextArticle` needs an ID passing):

```graphql
mutation markArticleCompleteMutation(
    $input: markArticleCompleteInput!
) {
    markArticleComplete(input: $input) {
        user {
            nextArticle(excludeArticleId: $excludeArticleId) {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Input looks like:

```json
{
  "input": {"completedId": "id123"}
}
```

how can I pass this from one of the input props?

I'd ideally like to write something like `nextArticle(excludeArticleId: $input.completedId)` but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot access it like this. You have to define a separate variable and use it.

Notice the `excludeArticleId` is added to the list of variables of your document and it is defined separately in the variables map.

```graphql
mutation markArticleCompleteMutation(
    $input: markArticleCompleteInput!,
    $excludeArticleId: String!
) {
    markArticleComplete(input: $input) {
        user {
            nextArticle(excludeArticleId: $excludeArticleId) {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the variables should be like this:

```json
{
    "input": {"completedId": "id123"},
    "excludeArticleId": "id123"
}
```

Comment: Hmm...so I'd need to pass this in everywhere I use the mutation? Seems a bit inelegant, but perhaps the only way.

Comment: Yes, according to the spec, you cannot access input objects inside a GraphQL document. So this seems like the option.